# HTTP 404 with PUT request in REST service

Tags: wcf, rest, url-routing, asp.net-4.0, wcf-rest

I am using the [WCF REST template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd) in VS 2010 to build RESTful web services for my app. I've completed all the GETs but am now trying to handle updates, and I keep getting 404 on the PUT even though it shows up in the help file.

Truncated `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
         type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </modules>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true" />
  <handlers>
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

As you can see, all verbs are enabled for the UrlRoutingHandler. What am I missing?

(Note that I am using IIS 7, but I'm forced to run the app pool in classic mode in order to emulate the behavior of the release server, which is on IIS 6.)

Answer (score 1):

After much troubleshooting the combination of the following two config changes seems to have fixed it.

1. Remove the WebDAV handler
2. Add PUT and DELETE verbs for ExtensionlessUrlHandler

(this is a placeholder to enable markdown code view below)

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"
       modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
       resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
       responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"
       modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
       resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
       responseBufferLimit="0" />
</handlers>
```